# Openstreetmap [OSM] not readable

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

The labelling of openstreetmap is hardly readable in QGIS. It has nothing to do with the zoom level. How can I change it to a readable layout?
[image]

Answer (score 9):

OSM Tiles are static png images. Qgis is rescaling them to achieve scale you've set. To get sharp images you have to match scale in qgis with a scale of tiles or render map locally using for example shapefiles from geofabrik. If you're using quickMapService plugin there is a function called "Set proper scale"

And following AndreJ's comment - you have to set project's SRS (CRS) to EPSG:3857

[image]

Comment: ... and set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857 if possible.

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ - obvious, but maybe not so obvious for OP